# Action from different XIB

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, ios4, xib

I am trying to do a action from a different XIB and class. I have been staring at this code for days, yes, days. Please help! Below is some code.

CaptionView.h file

```
#import "processViewController.h"
```

CaptionView.m file

```
processViewController *test = [[processViewController alloc] init];
[test startUploads];
```

processViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)startUploads {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startUploadsTwo) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (IBAction)startUploadsTwo {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

... code...

[pool release];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

For some reason the action is not being called. Any help is appreciated! - Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can't update the UI from worker threads. For this reason, you should change the `networkIndicator` from the main thread.

You can still trigger this from the worker though, using this method:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateSpinner:)
                            withObject:nil
                         waitUntilDone:false];
```

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The main thread encompasses the application’s main run loop, and is where the NSApplication object receives events.

This quotation refers to `NSApplication`, which is for OSX, but I imagine the same applies for `UIApplication` on iOS. Can't find an actual quote though.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! I also realized my database setup was in my viewDidLoad and since the user hasn't opened it up, the connection didn't happen. So I simply just copied the connection into that action and it works beautifully!

Comment: @phpnerd211: Great! Glad to have helped.